# OpenCL HelloWorld

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, opencl

I've just started working in opencl and I'm currently working on what should be a relatively basic hello_world program in opencl. Unfortunately the program is not outputting the proper phrase or anything at all it instead hangs with no output.

Any idea on why that is the case?

Below is: openglsource.cpp and hello.cl

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_0_APIS

#include<CL/cl.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

    auto platform = platforms.front();
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, &devices);

    auto device = devices.front();

    std::ifstream helloWorldFile("hello.cl");
    std::string src(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(helloWorldFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    cl::Program::Sources sources( 1, std::make_pair(src.c_str(), src.length() + 1));

    cl::Context context(device);
    cl::Program program(context, sources);

    auto err = program.build("-cl-std=CL1.2");

    char buf[16];
    cl::Buffer memBuf(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, sizeof(buf));
    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "Hello", &err);
    kernel.setArg(0, memBuf);

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);
    queue.enqueueTask(kernel);
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(memBuf, GL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(buf), buf);

    std::cout << "hello";
    std::cin.get();

}
```

hello.cl

```
__kernel void HelloWorld(__global char* data)
{
    data[0] = 'H';
    data[1] = 'E';
    data[2] = 'L';
    data[3] = 'L';
    data[4] = 'O';
    data[5] = ' ';
    data[6] = 'W';
    data[7] = 'O';
    data[8] = 'R';
    data[9] = 'L';
    data[10] = 'D';
    data[11] = '!';
    data[12] = '\n';
}
```

Comment: Your title says `OpenGL` but your question seems to be about `OpenGL`. Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming you meant to say OpenCL! At any rate the title has been updated.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistype trying to point out a mistype. In any way I am going to favorite your question since I have a great deal of difficulty with it as well. Upvote for you.

Comment: is your cpu intel? why are you using #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_0_APIS?

Comment: Yes it is intel! However, I downloaded the AMD APP SDK. #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_0_APIS and #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS both worked I accidentally left 2_0 in.

Comment: I'm just getting started myself so I'll make a comment instead of an answer because I may be real wrong here, but don't you have to work with get_global/local_id(0) in the kernels? Like "id = get_global_id(0); data[id] = hello[id];" where hello is simply an array ['H', 'E' .. llo worl .. 'D', '!', '\n']?

Comment: is CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU working? Please check all platforms. You could hae an eperimental 2.1 icd causing this 1.2 version fail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was in

```
 cl::Kernel kernel(program, "Hello", &err);
```

it should be

```
 cl::Kernel kernel(program, "HelloWorld", &err);
```

The string that goes there is not just an arbitrary name as I had inferred it should be the function that you want to call from the specified kernel. Which makes sense give that a kernel can hold multiple functions!

Such a simple fix.....I feel bad for posting!

Comment: Well, someone else googling "opencl hangs with no output" might find this helpful

Answer (score 1):

You should also change `GL_TRUE` to `CL_TRUE`